# Printing each row in a table if Follow Up? = "yes"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that loads data from Microsoft forms and has a spot for the reviewer to mark a response for follow up. I've tried looping through a selection with the macro below:

```
Sub TransposeAndPrint()
'
' TransposeAndPrint Macro
'
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRowSelected As Long
    
    For Each rng In Selection.Rows
    lRowSelected = rng.Row
        rng.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("B2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=True
        Range("A1:B15").Select
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    Next rng
    Sheets("STEP").Select
End Sub
```

This works sometimes, but often ends up with weird formatting. Also, when a user is selecting rows through a filtered table, the rows in between print.

I want a macro that goes through each row of my table and if [Follow Up? (Yes, No)]=yes then run the copy, transpose, paste, print routine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, so for simplicity I went with:

```
Sheets(2).UsedRange.autofilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="yes", VisibleDropDown:=False
Sheets(2).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```